# Writing a text scrambling algorithm backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

**Explanation**

I'm building a simple word scrambler/encoder in for fun. Given a seed and the text to convert, the algorithm to turn the original string illegible is to:

1. Loop through the characters of a user-given seed, say "lkj"
2. Loop through the characters of the text to convert, say "hello"
3. Get the index of both according to a list of accepted characters; so if `[a-z]` were characters that could be scrambled, and the loop was on index 0 for both the seed and conversion text, I'd get `l = index 11` and `h = index 7`
4. Add those two indices together. `11 + 7 = 18`. If the index exceeds the length of the accepted list, decrease that length from the new index (eg. `33 - 26`).
5. Get the character corresponding to index 18 on the accepted list. `s is at index 18`
6. Repeat until all the conversion characters have been looped through, returning the current seed index to 0 if the text exceeds the length of the seed

We end up with "souwy".

The algorithm to decode text (should be with the same seed) is just to do everything backwards. Start at the end of the string, start looping through the seed backwards at the index that it would stop at (`seed.length % text.length`), subtract indices instead of adding, then reverse the resulting string. So if we input "lkj" as the seed and "souwy" as the conversion text, we'll get "hello" back upon decoding.

**Problem**

The decoding seems to work only *sometimes*. With some combination of the seed and conversion text, the algorithm fails--but I have no idea what it could be. For example, using the following information:

> Seed: lkj
>
> Input: Hey guys! My email is yay@someDomain.com, but don't send me anything U_U

Decoding fails. However, if an 'x' is added to the end of the input, it works. What could be going wrong?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZ9FD/15/)

Comment: How about including the relevant parts of your code *in your question*? There is a lot of code in your fiddle and it'll make it a lot easier to get an answer if you can separate the relevant parts out.

Comment: @MattBurland Then I'd be including everything besides the short, marked off 'misc' section at the bottom, so I thought I might as well just link to the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an off by one error when the length of your message is a multiple of the length of your seed.

The problem line was:

```
var is_currSeed = (numLastWords > 0) ? (numLastWords - 1) : 0
```

should be changed to:

```
var is_currSeed = (numLastWords > 0) ? (numLastWords - 1) : seed.length - 1;
```

Here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/y8UP2/2/).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem! I noticed before that seed and the input being the same length failed, but the fix for that should've been added for multiples instead.

Comment: @idlackage - I did find the bug a minute after you accepted (and presumably found yourself).  Did we fix it the same way?

Comment: I did fix it before accepting, and in the same way. Giving the actual fix was very much appreciated though!